# ASP.Net - Conditions within a public class

Tags: asp.net, class, conditional-statements

I have this public class below and I want to include a condition which placed it inside and it doesn't work.  Any suggestions?

```
public SummaryDates GetSummaryDates()
    {

        SummaryDates result = new SummaryDates();
        var getDay = 3;
        DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
        var getMonth = 0;
        var getQuarter = 0;
        var quarterNow = now.AddMonths(3 * getQuarter);
        var quarterNumber = Math.Ceiling(quarterNow.Month / 3m);

        var quarterLabel2 = 0;
        var quarterLabel1 = 0;
        var quarterLabelA = 0;
        var quarterLabelB = 0;

        result.summaryDates = new SummaryDates
        {
           startOfQuarter2 = now,
            endOfQuarter2 = now,
            endOfQuarter2Plus1Day = now,
            endOfQuarter1Plus1Day = now,
            startOfQuarter1 = now,
            endOfQuarter1 = now,
            startOfQuarterA = now,
            startOfQuarterB = now,
            endOfQuarterA = now,
            endOfQuarterB = now,
            endOfQuarterAPlus1Day = now,
            endOfQuarterBPlus1Day = now,

    if (quarterNumber == 4)
        {
            startOfQuarter2 = new DateTime(getSummaryDates.quarter2Year, 10, 01);
            endOfQuarter2 = new DateTime(getSummaryDates.quarter2Year, 12, 31);
            endOfQuarter2Plus1Day = getSummaryDates.endOfQuarter2.AddDays(1);
            quarterLabel2 =  Convert.ToInt16(Math.Ceiling(getSummaryDates.endOfQuarter2.Month / 3m));

}
        return result;
       }
    }
```

I've placed the conditions inside.  It doesn't work.

Comment: It should work. Any error you got?

Comment: startOfQuarter2 = (quarterNumber == 4) ? now : new DateTime(getSummaryDates.quarter2Year, 10, 01)

Comment: what if it has 4 conditions?